# IID assumption in proportion hyp test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, iid

I am asked to test a hypothesis that a manufacturing line makes p% faulty parts in a month, it's assumed that the p% is independent of the month. My approach is as simple as it gets, take a random sample from this month and get the proportion and proceed with my test normally. However i am only provided with daily data ( example in day 1 4000 parts are produced and 150 were faulty ), does this violate the iiid of the data? given that i can only take " batches" of parts into my sample and those parts are dependent because they are produced in the same day?
I suppose i can try to prove there is no statistical significance in a chi-square test or something, but best i can do using this strategy is prove independence of the different weekdays or month days, but i cant prove if there was some special event or factors that i am not considering, for example workers get tired so the probability of getting a faulty part increases as the day goes by so the p% of faulty for each part is dependent of how many parts are produced before it. But if i can assume that there is no " special events ", could i argue that the samples are IID if i prove independence on month and weekdays?

edit: i realized that proving independence on weekdays and month days will only prove that different batches are independent.
Any suggestions on how I could handle this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How big is a batch? Do you have detailed information about the times when defective items were produced over a day? If you have such a time series, you can calculate its autoregression to see if your sample behaves like independent. Also if you have a time series of daily results over a month

Comment: Which test do you want to use? Do you have daily results over a loger period?

Comment: There is generally no way to "prove" independence of anything. Independence is an idealised model assumption that will never hold perfectly. The best you can ever do is try to find specific deviations from independence (such as dependence between subsequent days) and then find no evidence, i.e., no *specific* indication against independence.

Comment: When making judgements about i.i.d., always use any background knowledge you have. Don't rely on the data alone.  It will for sure depend on the specifics of the process. Are there reasons to believe that people work differently on Fridays or Mondays, and will this have an influence? This you can actually test. Are there reasons that the production process may depend on the season?

Comment: While @ChristianHenning is right that we cannot prove data independent, it should still be possible to detect some violations of independence that would grossly invalidate a test for the parameter (p%). So you can hope that your analysis is ok when you dont find evidence against independence, as Christian indicates. To be able to do that, you need more fine grained data, or at least data from several days.

Comment: i totally agree, total iid is more of a theoretical construct that we cant really prove, even with things like chi square test it's a weak conclusion.

Comment: @Ute i do have data over 2 years, but when i think about it, even if i tested and found no dependence or logic that supported dependence between data on different days, i still cant do anything about data on the same day, if i had 2 shifts, workers definitely have different error rates, so basically if have 500 pieces at day x , y parts are sampled from 1 dist and 500-y are samples from another dist so as far as independence is concerned i am safe but the identical assumption is violated

Comment: i agree that the only viable solution is to try to get finer grained data, maybe parts per hour would be enough

Comment: 2 years data, that is great! It would mean about 500 days, right? Do you also have data from the shifts, or just per day? What is a "dist"? the whole output from one workshop/plant/location, or something else?

Comment: another solution i am thinking off is to make my analysis " %faults per-day" basis, rather than faults per piece, this way i can assume i have a sample of iids of size 30, i guess in this case i would use an excat binomial test rather than a normal z test, but i cant think of anything going wrong off the top of my head, assuming that of course ( like @ChristianHennig said) there is no dependence shown in the data indicating days are not iid or any logic that might suggest so.

Comment: @Ute , sorry for the abbreviation, i meant distribution by "dist"; unfortunately, i dont have  any finer data than the day level; if i had per shift i could've done much more meaningful analysis, maybe make some analysis to monitor each shifts performance

Comment: @abdelrahmanesmat no worries, thanks for the clarification! If I understand you right, you know the total number of items produced by day, and the number of faults in a batch that you take each day. Or do you even know the total number of faulty items produced in a day?

Comment: It is great that you raise the question if your data are independent, or rather, the production of faulty items. This would be a prerequisite for a binomial model for the number of faulty items in a day. If there are circumstances like "one of the machines was not properly set up", then you could see a larger variance in faults per day than under a binomial distribution, and this could affect the validity of your test or confidence interval negatively.

Comment: @Ute for each day i have 2 numbers, total number produced , total number of faulty where produced includes the faulty

Comment: @Ute what do you think about the idea of taking the percentage of faulty parts per day ? i feel like i am missing something but no idea what.

Comment: if i take the overall error rate of each day i guess it's basically taking the average error rate of ( lets say 2 shifts a day ) , which wont be the best thing but i guess it's the best approximation i can do

Comment: Yes, I would recommend to take the percentage per day and not using a particular model. I will write some kind of general answer, and then you (or others) can object if there are things that are not correct :-)

Comment: @Ute please, go ahead. Can you also elaborate more what you mean by " not using a particular model" ?

Comment: @abdelrahmanesmat I meant not a specific model. I've tried to give a direction in my answer below :-)

Comment: Tracking a control chart would be a constructive solution because it would more clearly *show* you what is happening over time.

Comment: @whuber i agree that the field of statistical quality control offers a lot of way to monitor and improve the process, i am asking about this specific test though

Comment: I am completely ignorant of statistical quality control and think @whuber could be right - maybe your problem has been solved already there. It sounds generally relevant to me. So take my answer as a lay approach.

Comment: Same, i just read an introductory chapter in stat I.@whuber, could quality control solve our iid issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this question, the aim is to make inference for the average monthly rate $p$ of faulty items in a production line ($p$=number of faulty items per total). Daily count data are available over a long time period (2 years). The total number of items per day is large (thousands), and the failure rate is not very small (around 4-5%).

What makes the analysis difficult?

- There are good reasons to doubt that daily counts can be modelled as independent.
- Usually, one would model daily failure counts as binomial random variables, but that would require that there are no events that systematically affect larger batches of items, such as a manufacturing machine being faulty.

What could be done?

Look at the daily rates directly. They cannot be treated as i.i.d., but some analysis is possible anyway, at least if the daily total production does not vary extremely. A simplistic hands-on suggestion:

1.) Analyse daily rates as a time series: calculate the autocorrelation function, and from there, the effective sample size. Also try to see if there is some systematic or seasonal trend. If you are not familiar with time series, then maybe this [discussion of autocorrelation on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616173/what-does-it-mean-for-a-time-series-to-be-autocorrelated) can help to give some idea.

2.) If there is no trend, look at the distribution of the rates. Compare with a normal distribution e.g. using a normal qqplot.

3.) If modelling the daily rates as normal distributed is deemed ok, you can apply a test for the mean of a normal random variable, but use the effective sample size from 1.) instead of the true number of days, unless the time series did not have autocorrelation.
If the data deviate grossly from normal, a transformation might help. Commonly used simple resampling methods (bootstrap) are not recommended if you detected dependence in step 1.

Comment: well, nothing is recommended when you detect dependence not just bootstrapping: D.... but i believe this is the best we can do so far

Comment: What do you want to do, bootstrap? Waaaaa.... In that case, it should at least be some form of **block** bootstrap

Comment: from a quick read this might be a good solution, will have to read more about it as it's the first time i heard about " block bootstrapping "

Comment: I second the comment by @ChristianHenning (under your question) : try to investigate the dependence structure beforehand. Think of possible influences, such as weekday, and test if there is difference.